# d3.xml() In React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

How can I use `d3.xml()` in react application?
When I use below code, debugger does not access the function:

```
d3.xml("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle__black_simple.svg", 
function(error, documentFragment) {
    if (error) {console.log(error); return;}
    var svgNode = documentFragment.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    console.log(svgNode);
});
```

d3 was imported like this: `import * as d3 from "d3";`

Comment: The URL you are using is a 404 error. Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo (incorrect URL). This should have been obvious if you had used the Developer Tools built into your browser to check for errors and network requests.

Answer (score -2):

try to use fetch() instead of d3.xml()

Comment: Why doesn't d3.xml work? Why would using fetch instead fix the problem?